# How to create reusable React-Select in tsx?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I want to create a reusable [React-Select](https://react-select.com/home) in TSX.

What I am currently doing:

```
export const SelectInput: React.FC<SelectInputType> = ({
  className = "",
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <Select
      className={getClassName(className, styles["select-input"])}
      classNamePrefix={"select-input"}
      {...props}
    ></Select>
  );
};
```

How I am defining the type `SelectInputType`:

```
import { Props } from "react-select";
export type SelectInputType = Props;
```

But when using the component `SelectInput`, `onChange` event not work as required.

```
export const themes = ["light", "dark"] as const;

export type ThemeTypes = (typeof themes)[number];

type ThemeOptionType = {
  value: ThemeTypes;
  label: ThemeTypes;
};

export const ThemeChanger: React.FC = () => {
  const themeContext = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const options: ThemeOptionType[] = themes.map((themeName) => ({
    value: themeName,
    label: themeName,
  }));

  const onChange = (option: ThemeOptionType | null) => {
    themeContext?.toggleTheme(option ? option.value : "light");
  };

  return <SelectInput options={options} onChange={onChange} />
};
```

An Error occurs when using `SelectInput` `onChange`:

```
Type '(option: ThemeOptionType | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(newValue: unknown, actionMeta: ActionMeta<unknown>) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'option' and 'newValue' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ThemeOptionType | null'.
```